# VertX client implementation for connecting Solace VMR Server

Tags: vert.x, solace, solace-mq, vertx-verticle

How can we implement VertX Client connectivity to Solace VMR Server? We are connecting Solace VMR using VertX Standalone program as of now. Is there any standard implementation or patterns we can use for connecting solace VMR using VertX Cient like WAS or Tomcat  Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Solace supports the AMQP and MQTT protocols. You could use VertX to connect a client to Solace using these protocols.

Examples are listed from the vertx website:

- https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/mqtt-examples
- https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/amqp-bridge-examples

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to understand whether there is any way to connect IBM MQ using Vertx Client. We are trying to bridge IBM MQ to AMQP (which is on solace server). Please provide some information